# Prove that is a vectorial subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Given $I\subset \mathbb{R}$ an interval. I want to prove that $C_0(I)$, the set of continuous function $f:I\to \mathbb{R}$ that, for all $\epsilon>0$, $\{x\in I, |f(x)|\geq \epsilon\}$ is compact and that it is a vectorial subspace of $C_b(I)=\{f:I\to \mathbb{R}, \text{continuous}\}$.

We need to prove 2 items, the first is $f=0\in C_0(I)$ is clear, because suppose by contradiction, we don't have $\epsilon>0$ that satisfies what we want. The problem is $f+\lambda g\in C_0(I)$, $\lambda\in \mathbb{R}$ and $f,g\in C_0(\mathbb{R})$. Can somebody give me a hint? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: try it by proving closure under addition and scalar multiplication separately. Scalar multiplication is relatively straightforward. For the addition, consider $f, g \in C_0(I)$ and $\varepsilon > 0$, and begin by showing
\begin{align*}
\{x \in I : |f(x) + g(x)| \ge \varepsilon\} &\subseteq \{x \in I : |f(x)| + |g(x)| \ge \varepsilon\}\\
&\subseteq\left\{x \in I : |f(x)| \ge \frac{\varepsilon}{2}\right\} \cup \left\{x \in I : |g(x)| \ge \frac{\varepsilon}{2}\right\}.
\end{align*}
Hope that helps!

Comment: for the scalar, $X=\{x\in I, |\lambda g(x)|\geq \epsilon\}$ is compact because $X\subset \{x\in I, |g(x)|\geq \frac{\epsilon}{\lambda}\}$? Do i need separete in two cases? $\lambda>0$ and $\lambda<0$?

Comment: @user2345 You'll need two cases: $\lambda = 0$ and $\lambda \neq 0$. Write instead $\{x \in I : |g(x)| \ge \frac{\varepsilon}{|\lambda|}\}$ when $\lambda \neq 0$.

Comment: oh!!! its true!!! thanks